Flutter Firebase Hosting CORS policy config
I need to be able to access an external link for fetching some data but it is blocked by CORS policy. I created a cloud function in firebase which shall act as a proxy but still can't access the API due to the following error:

Request header field access-control-allow-methods is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

cloud function:
    const apiUrl = 'https://webservicesp.anaf.ro/PlatitorTvaRest/api/v8/ws/tva' + req.url; // Adjust the API URL as needed
    
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE,OPTIONS, HEAD, authorization');
        res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*'), // Required for CORS support to work
        res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
        res.set('Access-Control-Max-Age', '3600');
        res.status(200).send('');
        return;
    }

// Handle actual request
    cors(req, res, () => {
        // Your proxy logic here
        // Make sure to set appropriate CORS headers in your response

        // Forward the request to the API server
        fetch(apiUrl, {
            method: req.method,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":
                "*", // Required for CORS support to work
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials":
                'true', // Required for cookies, authorization headers with HTTPS
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":
                "Origin,Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,POST,HEAD,DELETE",
            "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
                // Include any additional headers needed by the API
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(req.body) // Forward request body if present
        })
        .then(apiRes => {
            // Set CORS headers in the response
            res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); // Allow requests from any origin
            res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE,OPTIONS, HEAD, authorization');
            res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
            // Forward API response back to client
            res.status(apiRes.status).json(apiRes.data);
             // Send response status code and body
            res.status(response.status).send(apiRes.body);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error proxying request:', error);
            res.status(500).send('Error proxying request');
        });
    });
});

What should I do to properly configure CORS?

The problem is that https://webservicesp.anaf.ro/PlatitorTvaRest/api/v8/ws/tva doesn't provide any CORS headers. Adding headers in your hosting environment won't make any difference. You may need to implement a service on your hosting that calls the anaf.ro API and returns the result.

@RichardHeap thank you. How do you suggest to do that? Is cloud functions an option?

That seems plausible, yes.

@RichardHeap could you support with this topic? Thank you!

Just search for examples, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43486393/how-to-make-an-http-request-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase
