# Mixed Content error after hosting react app with firebase. Is there an alternative way to host my project? Can I do modifications to my built code?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

Newbie React learner here!

I created a react app from scratch, using webpack and babel). In the application, there are many fetch requests. The API  URL has "HTTP" in front, and unfortunately, there isn't an https alternative for that. ( I tried putting an S or removing the / at the end but it didn't work).
 The project worked fine locally with no errors. I made some configuration setup in order to host it with firebase, and then built and deployed it. The setup worked also error-free, but when I visited the page I saw that there was no fetched content. When I checked the console there was the mixed content error for all the fetch requests.

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://yu-gi-oh-deck.firebaseapp.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://52.57.88.137/api/card_data/Burial%20from%20a%20Different%20>Dimension'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

To be honest, I have more than one questions, but there are all related to this project and how to move from here. I hope there isn't an issue with that.

1. Can I "undo" the firebase configuration from my project?
2. Are there other free options for hosting my app with no errors about https?
3. (it might be a stupid one). I haven't pushed the changes from the firebase setup to my Github repo.  Can I edit my project even after running build and deploy?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find some of your answer and possible solution: [Can sites on Firebase hosting include non-https resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34523385/can-sites-on-firebase-hosting-include-non-https-resources/46204382)

Look at this post to stop hosting: [How do I remove a hosted site from firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42591099/how-do-i-remove-a-hosted-site-from-firebase)

This is a post to host your single page app on GitHub: https://itnext.io/so-you-want-to-host-your-single-age-react-app-on-github-pages-a826ab01e48

You can still edit your project, it has nothing to do with Firebase hosting.

Comment: Thank you! I will check the links.